# How to set a time limit to a task if not excute within a certain time then just remove it in celery

Tags: python, celery

I'm using celery(rabbitmq as broker) to do many tasks every minute.Since the task is a little time-consuming, the tasks in the queue may accumulate which leads to the newest come task not excute in time. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find it in the document:

[Expiration](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html?highlight=expiration#expiration)

```
add.apply_async(args=[10, 10], expires=60)
```

[Task Expires](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=expires#celery.app.task.Task.expires)

```
@task(expires=50)
```